# Protractor - Opening downloads by sending CTRL + J

Tags: protractor

Using Protractor automation, I'm trying to open the downloads bar in a new tab via CTRL + J so it will be removed (the bar is hiding elements I need to click on...)  I've tried:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, 'j')).perform();
```

```
browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).sendKeys('j').perform();
```

nothing happens, the downloads page isn't open and the downloads bar still displays.

Comment: Share the error msg and the ui to give better idea on the issue.

Comment: There is no error message, they keystrokes don’t appear to be passed into the browser

Comment: Face this issue here, is there any solution? The combination work for Ctrl + A, but not for Ctrl + J / W / T